# pass arguments to apache-ant exec task based on the variable's value

Tags: apache, ant, if-statement, exec

I am only using `apache-ant` and **not** `ant-contrib`

I have an `ant` target

```
<target name="stop" depends="init" >
...
</target>
```

In which i want to invoke `exec` task.

If the value of a variable `HOST_NAME` is `all`

```
<exec executable="${executeSSH.shell}" >
    <arg value="-h ${HOST_NAME}" />
    <arg value="-i ${INSTANCE}" />
    <arg value="-w 10" />
    <arg value="-e ${myOperation.shell} " />
    <arg value=" -- " />
    <arg value="${INSTANCE} ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}" />
</exec>
```

If the value of a variable `HOST_NAME` is `anything else`

```
<exec executable="${executeSSH.shell}">
    <arg value="-h ${HOST_NAME}" />
    <arg value="-i ${INSTANCE}" />
    <arg value="-e ${myOperation.shell} " />
    <arg value=" -- " />
    <arg value="${INSTANCE} ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}" />
</exec>
```

**But i would like to write only one task and not to repeat**`exec`. I have used `HOST_NAME` parameter but what to do about the second parameter `-w 10` which is different in both calls.

I have tried a couple of ways by searching on SO by using `condition` and `if else` but nothing seems to be applicable for `exec` or `arg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using macrodef. The following example is not tested.

```
<macrodef name="callSSH">
    <element name="extArgs" optional="y"/>
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="${executeSSH.shell}" >
            <arg value="-h ${HOST_NAME}" />
            <arg value="-i ${INSTANCE}" />
            <extArgs/>
            <arg value="-e ${myOperation.shell} " />
            <arg value=" -- " />
            <arg value="${INSTANCE} ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}" />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef> 
<target name="stop" depends="init" >
    <if>
       <equals arg1="${HOST_NAME}" arg2="all"/>
        <then>
            <callSSH>
                <extArgs>
                    <arg value="-w 10" />
                </extArgs>
            </callSSH>
        </then>
        <else>
            <callSSH>
                <extArgs/>
            </callSSH>
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

Or if you don't use contribs:

```
<target name="sshExecWithHost" if="HOST_NAME"> 
    <callSSH>
        <extArgs>
            <arg value="-w 10" />
        </extArgs>
    </callSSH>
</target>

<target name="sshExecNoHost" unless="HOST_NAME">
    <callSSH/>
</target>

<target name="sshSwitch" depends="sshExecNoHost,sshExecWithHost">
</target>

<target name="stop" depends="init,sshSwitch" >
</target>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the condition task:

```
<condition property="my.optional.arg" value="-w 10" else="">
    <equals arg1="${HOST_NAME}" arg2="all" />
</condition>

<exec executable="${executeSSH.shell}" >
    <arg value="-h ${HOST_NAME}" />
    <arg value="-i ${INSTANCE}" />
    <arg line="${my.optional.arg}" />
    <arg value="-e ${myOperation.shell} " />
    <arg value=" -- " />
    <arg value="${INSTANCE} ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Very helpful, tried a thousand different variations and this is finally what did the trick.

Comment: This is great and compact. I used it to conditionally generate code coverage reports based on a build parameter.